# Property binding of indexed List item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've googled this a little, but can't seem to find a source that explains why this doesn't work.

If I have this bit of code:

```
public class FastData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IList<FastDataVectors> fdvectors;
    public IList<FastDataVectors> fdVectors {get { return fdvectors; } set { if (fdvectors == value) return; SetProperty(ref fdvectors, value); } }

    private IList<float> fdfloat;
    public IList<float> fdFloat {get { return fdfloat; } set { if (fdfloat == value) return; SetProperty(ref fdfloat, value); } }
...
}

public class FastDataVectors : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private float fdvangle;
    public float fdvAngle {get { return fdvangle; } set { if (fdvangle == value) return; SetProperty(ref fdvangle, value); } }
...
}

private FastData myfastdata;
public FastData myFastData {get { return myfastdata; } set { if (myfastdata == value) return; SetProperty(ref myfastdata, value); } }

private List<FastDataVectors> myfastdatavectors;
public List<FastDataVectors> myFastDataVectors {get { return myfastdatavectors; } set { if (myfastdatavectors == value) return; SetProperty(ref myfastdatavectors, value); } }

...
myFastData = new FastData();
myFastData.fdVectors = new List<FastDataVectors>();
myFastData.fdVectors.Add(new FastDataVectors() {fdvAngle = 10});   
myFastData.fdVectors.Add(new FastDataVectors() {fdvAngle = 20});

myFastData.fdFloat.Add(10);
myFastData.fdFloat.Add(20);
```

and this text block in XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myFastData.fdVectors[0].fdvAngle}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myFastData.fdVectors[1].fdvAngle}"/>
```

I would expect it to display "10 & 20", but I just get a binding error, which oddly is "...Specified argument was out of the range of valid values".

However if I try this piece of XAML it works perfectly:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myFastData.fdFloat[0]}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myFastData.fdFloat[1]}"/>
```

I don't really know what I'm searching for and the first few pages of a google search on "wpf c# binding property index array list", don't return anything that may explain this.

So the question is really twofold:

1) why doesn't this work?

2) other than how I've worked around it, is there a better way of fixing what I want to do?

Note: This is a simplified code chunk I've just written and may contain errors and the odd bit of code omission to illustrate.

Edit: I've updated the code to better represent what I'm actually doing. I also can't use ObservableCollection as I am using the Telerik DataAccess tools, which backs the class off to a SQLite DB. Even looking at the customising fluent collections approach Telerik have documented, isn't possible in my scenario as the main data classes are in a PCL, which are limiting me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because WPF has no way of knowing that you've added anything to `fdVectors`.

You need to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` if you want WPF to react to additions/subtractions.

Either that or your posted code is not what you're running. I'm struggling to see how this even compiles:

```
myFastDataVectors = new List<FastDataVectors>();
myFastDataVectors.fdvAngle = 10;
```

Is `myFastDataVectors` a `List` or a `FastDataVectors`?

Comment: You're right, the code wasn't right. I've updated now. I'm forced into using IList, as it's all being used with the Telerik DataAccess tools, which backs off to a SQLite DB. An ObservableCollection, which I used to use extensively, have all been replaced with ILists. Now I'm building the UI in a more structured way, I hit this issue. I was under the impression that the IList still gave you the notification triggers when stuff changed.

Comment: The reason I thought that is that the float value, which is a List of Floats gets updated in the UI without any issue

Comment: I can only assume that you're somehow triggering a binding update after you've added the floats.(like setting myFastData on something). Again, can only guess as can't see the real code.

Comment: Can you populate `fdVectors` before adding it to `myFastData`? That would work around the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. How do I populate fdVectors before adding it to myFastData? Am I not doing that by creating a FastDataVectors list before then adding that to myFastData? - I'm actually getting around this by creating a separate reference to the List, so I can use the in XAML. Similar to the fdFloat I use above, but not actually in the class that gets used in the database.

Comment: Probably more code confusion. Your line `myFastData.fdVectors.Add(myFastDataVectors);` looks like it's adding to an existing list, but I suspect you meant `myFastData.fdVectors = myFastDataVectors;` which is what I was suggesting you do to fix.

Comment: The code I actually have has many properties and is a whole lot more complicated. But the only difference I can see, now I've really looked harder, is I add it directly: myFastData.fdVectors.Add(new FastDataVectors() {fdvAngle = 10}); Doing it either way in my code doesn't work. I think you're right with your comment about the XAML not knowing it's changed. The code behind watch certainly works and the DB is updated. It's just the UI  that never changes. I'll carry on with the duplicate list of FastDataVectors directly and then reference that in the XAML, as I know that works. Thanks...

Comment: I'll keep the question open for a day or so to see if anyone can offer a better way around this. Failing that I'll mark your's as the answer. Thanks again...